# System.UnauthorizedAccessException em C#

Tags: c#

Bom, estou tentando desenvolver um setup automático para um programa que desenvolvi. Primeiro, criaria uma pasta em C:/NomeDaPasta; Em seguida, ele baixaria um repositório do Github como **.zip** nesta pasta, depois exportaria o zip para ela e finalmente removeria o .zip. Falta adicionar algo para executar o setup, mas o problema não é aí.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace C_Sharp_WIndowsFormTest
{
    class setup
    {
public static void download(string url, string path, string githubToken)
    {

        using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
        {
            var credentials = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}:", githubToken);
            credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(credentials));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", credentials);
            var contents = client.GetByteArrayAsync(url).Result;
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, contents);
        }

    }

    public static void JustDoIt()
    {

        string directory = "C:/NomeDaPasta";
        string githubToken = "MeuGithubToken";
        string url = "UrlDoRepositório";

        if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
        {

            /*## Cria a Pasta##*/

            Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
            download(url, directory, githubToken);
            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory("C:/NomeDaPasta/Repositório.zip", directory);

            /*## Deleta o zip ##*/
            File.SetAttributes(directory, FileAttributes.Normal);
            File.Delete("C:/NomeDaPasta/Repositório.zip");

            /*## Final (Deleta a pasta) ##*/
            Directory.Delete(directory);


        }
        else
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Folder already exists!");
            Directory.Delete(directory);
            JustDoIt();

        }

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {

            JustDoIt();             

        } catch (Exception e)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());

        }

    }

}

}
```

**NOTA:** Eu apenas copiei o código do Download de [outra pessoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408053/c-sharp-example-of-downloading-github-private-repo-programmatically).

Este é o código, porém ao executá-lo, me devolve o seguinte erro:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: O acesso ao caminho 'C:/NomeDaPasta' foi negado.
```

Já procurei por ajuda, mas não tive sucesso. Por favor, alguém me ajude!

Comment: você já tentou fazer o processo em outro diretório sem ser na raiz da Unidade C://? Tipo tente fazer em outra pasta fora da C:/NomeDaPasta, como você está fazendo.

Comment: Já tentou dar permissão na pasta?

Comment: @WesleyHeron até faria mas como o caminho seria definido, já que pode variar de pc a pc? Se tiver alguma maneira por favor me diga!

Comment: @jbueno segui um tutorial para adicionar permissão ao programa usando visual studio( a IDE que uso ) aparentemente deveria funcionar mas não.

Comment: Por que não adiciona permissão usando o próprio Windows? Botão direito do mouse em cima da pasta > **Propriedades** > **Segurança**, etc.

Comment: mas isso não se aplicaria a todos os computadores, todos que quisessem baixar meu programa teriam de fazer isto, e nao quero isso.

Comment: Veja se ajuda https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setaccesscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Voce pode executar a sua aplicação como administrador. Aliás, voce pode indicar que a aplicação deve ser executada apenas com direitos de administrador. Para isso voce tem que criar um manifesto para a sua aplicação .

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E tem que mudar as permissões para administrador

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-do-i-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator)

Para evitar executar a sua aplicacao como administrador escreva noutro sitio tal como

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

Comment: Como é um instalador creio que nao haja problema em executar como administrador

Answer (score 1):

Substitua estes pontos:

`string directory = @"C:\\NomeDaPasta";`

`string caminhoZip = @"C:\\NomeDaPasta\\Repositório.zip";`

`ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(caminhoZip, directory);`

`File.Delete(caminhoZip);`

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa editar as opções de segurança da pasta, pois o processo que está chamando as funções de criação e deleção de pastas, não tem as credenciais de Leitura e/ou gravação para realizar tal operação.

Você pode confirmar isto trocando o caminho para um genérico para fazer o teste:

```
string directory = @"C:\\Users\\Public\\Teste";
```

Com este caminho (que por sinal é mais acessível), você vai conseguir gerar o que precisa.